# autocomplete search bar with dropdown menu

Tags: php

what i wanna do is this https://i.gyazo.com/5ba7b0ecbd877c4b8b432cf9d55bb848.gif  but i have been trying to do it now for 2 days with no progress,
but what i have right now is this https://i.gyazo.com/1fad863c3c1379e9de8107bfd349377e.gif and i dont really know how to make it into what i want

my code:

```
<?php



    include("db-tilkobling.php");

    $sqlSetning="SELECT navn FROM flyplass ORDER BY lokasjon;";
    $sqlResultat=mysqli_query($db,$sqlSetning) or die ("ikke mulig å hente data fra databasen");

    $antallRader=mysqli_num_rows($sqlResultat);

    for ($r=1;$r<=$antallRader;$r++)
    {
        $rad=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlResultat);
        $navn=$rad["navn"];


        print("<option value='$navn'> $navn</option>");
    }
?>
```

in a different php file:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="billett" name="billett" onsubmit = "">
    Fly fra <select name='navn' id='navn'>
        <?php include("klasse-boks.php"); ?>
    </select>
    Fly til <select name='navn' id='navn'>
        <?php include("klasse-boks.php"); ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Søk og Bestill" id="fortsett" name="fortsett">
</form>
```

Comment: i want the combination of the two, a search bar with a drop downlist, and with the arrow at the end that gives the user the option to use just the dropdown menu

Comment: you can use jquery.it is good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jquery, There is an autocomplete feature, simple and good.

For jquery autocomplete,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

For autocomplete,

```
   <script>

    $(function() {
        $( "#countries" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'countries.php'
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Here we will have an id called 'countries', and we can create another PHP script for getting the data. You can see in the above code.

And our HTML will be like this

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="countries">Countries: </label>
    <input id="countries">
</div>
```

Finally, PHP source file,

We can get the textbox value by term field `($_GET['countries'])` from the query string. Now we will fetch the data from skills table and filtering the skills by `$_GET['countries']`. At last we will return the filtered skills data in `JSON` format.

```
<?php
    //database configuration
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'countries'; //database name

    //connect with the database
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

    //get search term
    $searchTerm = $_GET['countries'];

    //get matched data from countries table
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE country LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY country ASC");

    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $data[] = $row['country'];
    }

    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I hope you got an idea. And you can learn it. This is not for **points/upvotes**. Good luck.

Comment: i'm pretty sure i am doing this wrong, i did what you said but what i'm getting is just this https://i.gyazo.com/891a54af62b606f6ff6bf1ec80a30761.png these are my files 

jquery:

https://i.gyazo.com/6e7e060813090e784fcbd49b62f6fcbc.png


php:

https://i.gyazo.com/9e593fb3b3e1746ff54fc8fa20569db1.png

html:
https://i.gyazo.com/22d4e07b3ff249ab9cd479bd574f3940.png

Comment: just see the result from php script? what is it?

Comment: bro, i found another example. You should learn. Also search on google if you don't know any php function. anyway learn this. https://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/php-autocomplete-tutorial-using-jquery/

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: flyplass in D:\Sites\home.hbv.no\139987\EKSAMEN 2016\countries.php on line 13
["Frankfurt","London","Oslo","Sola"]

on line 13:     $searchTerm = $_GET['flyplass'];
flyplass is countries table

Comment: print the result from php. check for the line no 13.